# Codeigniter Active Record is only selecting the first record instead of the most recent

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

My problem is pretty simple. I'm using codeigniter active record, and all the model class has to do is select the most recent item from a table that belongs to the user.

```
function get_progress($users_id)
 {
  $query = $this->db->get('progress');
  $this->db->where('user_key', $users_id);
  $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
  $this->db->limit(1);
  return $query->row_array();
 }
```

Seems simple, but for some reason, it's grabbing the lowest id that matches the user_key.

I've tried changing the where statement to

```
  $this->db->where('id', '2');
```

And it works, but of course, that's just for troubleshooting. I need variables.

I've rewritten few ways, including using get_where(), and changing desc to asc. No matter what, it's grabbing the low id. How can I select the highest id where user_key is the matching number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try the code below**

```
function get_progress($users_id){
  return $this->db->from('progress')
  ->where('user_key', $users_id)
  ->order_by("id", "DESC")
  ->get()
  ->row();
}
```

You will get the last recent row as STD Class object

Comment: This returns undefined index when using the results, so I don't think it's a valid query.

Comment: for std class you have to use like 
 $row = $this->My_model->get_progress($users_id);
 <?php echo $row->column_name; ?>

Comment: Are you sure that active record allows chaining in that syntax. I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: use var_dump($query_from_model); exit(); in your controller

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty
I'm pretty sure that your query is broken. I've never seen that syntax before. I'm pretty sure the $this->db and a ; at the end is required for each operation of the active record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67744/discussion-between-touhid-and-goose).

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_progress($users_id)
{
        $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('progress')
        ->where('user_key',$users_id)
        ->order_by('id','desc')
        ->limit(1);
        $q=$this->db->get();
        return $q->result_array();
}
```